# Como fazer o fwrite escrever apenas o caractere ao invés do registro inteiro?

Tags: c, c++

Estou fazendo um código que lê um arquivo com registros de tamanho fixo (armazenando no `struct` `hist`), e insere elas em outro arquivo formatando para que tenham tamanho variável.
Para indicar que o `struct` já foi inserido, estou escrevendo `*` no início do registro no arquivo de inserção.

```
fread(&hist, sizeof(hist), 1, insereCopia);     // faz a leitura de insereCopia

while(hist.ID_aluno[0] == '*'){                 // verifica qual o próximo registro a ser inserido
    fread(&hist, sizeof(hist), 1, insereCopia);
    cont++;
}

fseek(insereCopia, cont * sizeof(hist), SEEK_SET);      // volta ao início do reg para definir o seu tamanho e indicar que ele já foi inserido

fwrite("*", sizeof(char), 1, insereCopia);
```

Porém, ao invés de `fwrite` escrever só o caractere `*` ele está inserindo sempre o primeiro registro junto no arquivo de inserção. Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Veja: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example aqui em meu teste a escrita funcionou como o esperado.

Answer (score 0):

você também pode usar fputc(int caractere, FILE* arquivo)
para apenas um caractere

```
fputc('*',insereCopia);
```

*obs: também existe a possibilidade das ultimas alterações não estarem sendo salvas por faltar de um fclose(file) (para fechar o arquivo)

*obs2: um arquivo aberto só como escrita, apaga tudo oque já havia nele antes, e um arquvio só escrita com "append"("w+"), ira escrever apenas depois de tudo oque já foi escrito na hora em que foi aberto(o fseek não ira funcionar para ponteiros antes deste ponto), então tbm não use "append", no seu caso (fopen), o equivalente ao "append" é o caractere '+'.

o resultado vai ser o mesmo provavelmente, não vejo erro nesta parte...
provavelmente, oque você está vendo a mais, são os dados anteriores, abrindo um arquivo como escrita e leitura simultânea, as suas escritas iram sobrescrever byte a byte os dados existentes, exemplo:

abro um arquivo, movo o ponteiro para 5, escrevo '*', oque acontece:

"texto dentro do arquivo"

012345<ponteiro

saida:

"texto*dentro do arquivo"

**Abordagem Diferente, abstração**

```
struct Hist {
    //variáveis...{
}
struct HistFile {
    FILE* file;
    HistFile(char* filepath) {//...abrir arquivo
    ~HistFile() {//...fechar arquivo
    int getCount() {
        fseek (file , 0 , SEEK_END);
        return ftell (pFile) / sizeof(Hist);
    }
    Hist get(int index) {
        fseek(file,index*sizeof(Hist),SEEK_SET);
        Hist ret;
        fread((const void*)&ret, sizeof(Hist), 1, file);
        return ret;
    }
    void set(Hist h, int index) {
        fseek(file,index*sizeof(Hist),SEEK_SET);
        fwrite((const void*)&h, sizeof(Hist, 1, file);
    }
}
```